# How to pivot row data using Informatica?

Tags: pivot, data-warehouse, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

How can I pivot row data using Informatica PowerCenter Designer? Say, I have a source file called address.txt:

```
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
| ADDR_ID |     NAME     |     ADDRESS     |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
|       1 | John Smith   | JohnsAddress1   |
|       1 | John Smith   | JohnsAddress2   |
|       2 | Adrian Smith | AdriansAddress1 |
|       2 | Adrian Smith | AdriansAddress2 |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
```

I would like to Pivot this data like this:

```
+---------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| ADDR_ID |     NAME     |    ADDRESS1     |    ADDRESS2     |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|       1 | John Smith   | JohnsAddress1   | JohnsAddress2   |
|       2 | Adrian Smith | AdriansAddress1 | AdriansAddress2 |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

How can I do this in Informatica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every person has two addresses, you can use the `FIRST` and `LAST` functions in an `Aggregator` transformation:

[image: Aggregator transformation]!