# How to pivot data using Informatica when you have variable amount of pivot rows?

Tags: pivot, data-warehouse, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Based on my [earlier questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294198/how-to-pivot-row-data-using-informatica), how can I pivot data using Informatica PowerCenter Designer when I have variable amount of Addresses in my data. I would like to Pivot e.g four addresses from my data. This is the structure of the source data file:

```
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
| ADDR_ID |     NAME     |     ADDRESS     |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
|       1 | John Smith   | JohnsAddress1   |
|       1 | John Smith   | JohnsAddress2   |
|       1 | John Smith   | JohnsAddress3   |
|       2 | Adrian Smith | AdriansAddress1 |
|       2 | Adrian Smith | AdriansAddress2 |
|       3 | Ivar Smith   | IvarAddress1    |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
```

And this should be the resulting table:

```
+---------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+----------+
| ADDR_ID |     NAME     |    ADDRESS1     |    ADDRESS2     |   ADDRESS3    | ADDRESS4 |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+----------+
|       1 | John Smith   | JohnsAddress1   | JohnsAddress2   | JohnsAddress3 | NULL     |
|       2 | Adrian Smith | AdriansAddress1 | AdriansAddress2 | NULL          | NULL     |
|       3 | Ivar Smith   | IvarAddress1    | NULL            | NULL          | NULL     |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+----------+
```

I guess I can use

SOURCE --> SOURCE_QUALIFIER --> SORTER --> AGGREGATOR --> EXPRESSION --> TARGET TABLE

But what kind of port should I use in AGGREGATOR and EXPRESSION transforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something along the lines of this:

```
Source->Expression->Aggregator->Target
```

In the expression, add a variable port:

```
v_count expr: IIF(ISNULL(v_COUNT) OR v_COUNT=3, 1, v_COUNT + 1)
```

OR

```
v_count expr:  IIF(ADDR_ID=v_PREVIOUS_ADDR_ID, v_COUNT + 1, 1)
```

And 3 output ports:

```
o_addr1 expr: DECODE(TRUE, v_COUNT=1, ADDR_IN, NULL)
o_addr2 expr: DECODE(TRUE, v_COUNT=2, ADDR_IN, NULL)
o_addr3 expr: DECODE(TRUE, v_COUNT=3, ADDR_IN, NULL)
```

Then use the aggregator, group by ID and select always the Max,
e.g.

```
agg_addr1: expr: MAX(O_ADDR1)
agg_addr2: expr: MAX(O_ADDR2)
agg_addr3: expr: MAX(O_ADDR3)
```

If you need more denormalized ports, add additional ports and set the initial state
of the v_count variable accordingly.

Comment: Will this work for variable amount for addresses? Shouldn't you order data by `ADDR_ID` and reset `v_count` on every `ADDR_ID` change?

Comment: It won't work for variable amount of addresses, you need to at least specify a maximum, but should be no more of a problem as you also need to have a target with a fixed number of attributes (unless you want to write to a CSV file). And yes, you need to group by ADDR_ID and also reset the v_count variable on ADDR_ID change. I don't think you need to order the data, since you can in the Source qualifier hit the Order checkbox, so you save the order transformation which makes the mapping more efficient

Comment: I pointed this out because the OP explicitly asked about pivoting a variable number of rows and included appropriate source data sample.

Comment: Indeed. But I don't know any way of doing this without putting there a fixed limit (Well you could try adding a really high limit like 999 or so). If you really need pivoting, I would use another tool. Rapidminer comes to mind.

Comment: How about `v_count = IIF(ADDR_ID=v_previous_ADDR_ID, v_count+1, 1)`? Of course there will still be a maximum number of addresses that can be handled (in the `DECODE` statements, in the target definition) but this way the counter will work properly both for 4 addresses as well as 3, 2 or 1. You counter will assign 1, 2, 3 to `John Smith`, then 1, 2 to `Adrian Smith` and finally 3 to `Ivar Smith` - am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

SOURCE --> SOURCE_QUALIFIER --> RANK --> AGGREGATOR -->TARGET

In RANK transformation, group by on ADDR_ID and select ADDRESS as rank port. In properties tab, select Number of ranks as 4.

In AGGREGATOR transformation group by on ADDR_ID and use the following output port expressions (RANKINDEX will be generated by RANK transformation):

```
ADDRESS1 = MAX(ADDRESS,RANKINDEX=1)
ADDRESS2 = MAX(ADDRESS,RANKINDEX=2)
ADDRESS3 = MAX(ADDRESS,RANKINDEX=3)
ADDRESS4 = MAX(ADDRESS,RANKINDEX=4)
```