# convert rows into Column informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

could you please let me know how to transform the rows into Column in powerCenter?
attached the Snapshot below.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pivot data using Informatica when you have variable amount of pivot rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300969/how-to-pivot-data-using-informatica-when-you-have-variable-amount-of-pivot-rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is an aggregator - group by *Product* and add two output ports to calculate the product value:

- *Current_value* - `MAX(IIF(end date = 1231999, Value, NULL))`
- *Future_value* - `MAX(IIF(end date = 01010001, Value, NULL))`

**UPDATE:**

PowerCenter aggregate functions take an optional `filter_condition` parameter, so you can also use the equivalent, more concise syntax:

- *Current_value* - `FIRST(Value, end date = 1231999)`
- *Future_value* - `FIRST(Value, end date = 01010001)`