# Transformation required to load data from multiple rows to one column

Tags: informatica-powercenter

What are the transformation required to load data from multiple rows of source to one column of target in below scenario.

source

Dept_No      Name

- 10              A
- 11              B
- 10              C
- 10              D
- 12              E
- 12              F

Target

Dept_No      Name

- 10              A, C, D
- 11              B
- 12              E,F

Comment: This action is called pivoting. Look at these: https://community.informatica.com/solutions/pivot_data_aggregator and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atJb42Qq2rc

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pivot data using Informatica when you have variable amount of pivot rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300969/how-to-pivot-data-using-informatica-when-you-have-variable-amount-of-pivot-rows)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use expression transformation and implementing kind of loop inside the transformation,comparing current row value and previous row values. Please,check detailed answer here: http://data-point.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/loading-data-from-multiple-rows-to-one_19.html